# How to sync database in eclipse with sqlite browser

Tags: android, sqlite, data-synchronization

I am starting with DBHandling. I have performed CRUD operation and i want them to see instatntly in my DB.

I have pull the DB from file explorer in eclipse and open that DB in sqlite browser, but i want to reduce my effort, what i want is when i perform some operation on DB, all the changes in DB should be visible to me instantly.. i dont want to pull the DB again and open in sqlite.

please suggest some alternative.

Thanks for reading the query and giving your time

Comment: The easiest way I have found is simply editing your db that is stored within the assets folder. This will then automatically update everytime (although, if you add new tables or columns then you need to uninstall the app first).

Comment: This may also help http://wiki.eclipse.org/Connecting_to_SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your eclipse,
Go to DDMS,
Select file explorer(there you will get the list of emulators, select one if you launched more then one),
Go to data,
in that there is another sub folder named data,
now you will get the package name of list of installed apps, 
select you app,
in that you will find db if you created , 
you can pull and push that db

Comment: but with this approach i have to pull again and again as i put some data in .db file.\n If i enter some data in DB i want to see its immediate effect in sql browser. i dont want to pull again a updated database

Comment: then place the db file in the assets and get the db path, and use that file, to update , it possible .. so then you can check the immediate updates..